# MongoDB find query using $or and count

Tags: mongodb

I got stuck with small problem in mongodb using $or query, I have a collection with documents having below schema. It has a **role** and **skill_set** keys, each role has some skill set associated.

```
[
{
    "skill_set" : [ 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Project Planning"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Delivery Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Resource Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Stakeholder Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Agile Project Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Change Management"
        }
    ],
    "role" : "Project Manager"
},
{
    "skill_set" : [ 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Project Planning"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Delivery Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Resource Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Stakeholder Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Agile Project Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Change Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Financial Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Sales, Marketing and Customer Service "
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Strategic Input"
        }
    ],
    "role" : "Sr Project Manager"
},
{
    "skill_set" : [ 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Project Planning"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Delivery Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Resource Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Stakeholder Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Agile Project Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Change Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Financial Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Sales, Marketing and Customer Service "
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Strategic Input"
        }
    ],
    "role" : "Delivery Manager"
},
{
    "skill_set" : [ 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Test Planning"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Technlogy Expertise"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Team Player"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Communication"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Design and Architecture"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Requirement Understanding"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Task Management"
        }
    ],
    "role" : "Tester"
}
]
```

I want to search documents with **role** matching skill_set, which I am able to fetch using query.

```
{"$or":[{"skill_set.skill_name":"Project Planning"},{"skill_set.skill_name":"Strategic Input"},{"skill_set.skill_name":"Delivery Management"}]},{"_id":0}
```

**Output for Query**

```
[
{
    "skill_set" : [ 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Project Planning"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Delivery Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Resource Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Stakeholder Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Agile Project Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Change Management"
        }
    ],
    "role" : "Project Manager"
},
{
    "skill_set" : [ 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Project Planning"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Delivery Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Resource Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Stakeholder Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Agile Project Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Change Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Financial Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Sales, Marketing and Customer Service "
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Strategic Input"
        }
    ],
    "role" : "Sr Project Manager"
},
{
    "skill_set" : [ 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Project Planning"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Delivery Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Resource Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Stakeholder Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Agile Project Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Change Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Financial Management"
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Sales, Marketing and Customer Service "
        }, 
        {
            "skill_name" : "Strategic Input"
        }
    ],
    "role" : "Delivery Manager"
}
]
```

In output it is clearly visible, 3 out 4 roles are fetched. In addition to this I want the count of skill set matching to role .ie.

**In given query I am searching for role with Project Planning or Delivery Management or Strategic Input, I want skill_match_count = 2 for role Project Manager it has 2 match in his skill sets i.e. I want something like below.**

```
[
{
    "role" : "Project Manager",
    "skill_match_count" : 2 
},
{
    "role" : "Sr Project Manager",
    "skill_match_count" : 3
},
{
    "role" : "Delivery Manager",
    "skill_match_count" : 3
}
]
```

Comment: the example output does not match the example documents. For example, `Project Manager` has 6 skills and in your output you show 2. So is is a mistake? I don't really understand what are you counting.

Comment: @tom this count is only for matching skills i.e. for "Project Manger" Role 2 skills from given above query match. I hope I had clear my question.

Comment: I think you can approach it by using mongo `aggregation` feature. Please have a try.

Comment: @gzc thanks for the help. Can you help with query?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do, is to `$filter` the `skill_set` array with your `$or` condition and then `$project` the `$size` of your filtered array:

```
db.roles.aggregate([
  {
      $project: {
          role: 1,
          filtered_skill_set: {
              $filter: {
                  input: "$skill_set",
                  as: "skill",
                  cond: {
                      $or: [
                          { $eq: ["$$skill.skill_name", "Project Planning"] },
                          { $eq: ["$$skill.skill_name", "Strategic Input"] },
                          { $eq: ["$$skill.skill_name", "Delivery Management"] }
                      ]
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  },
  {
      $project: {
          role: 1,
          skill_match_count: {
              $size: "$filtered_skill_set"
          }
      }
  }
])
```

This will result the output you expect including roles with 0 in the `skill_match_count`. If you want to exclude them, you can add another `$match` pipeline stage at the end:

```
{
    $match: {
        skill_match_count: {
            $gt: 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any news? waiting for approval :D